# Linq and EF on .Any()

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I use c#, linq and EF4.

I have two tables in my DataBase represented in my Conceptual Model:

DataBase Tables:

```
CmsContents
CmsCategories
CmsRelatedCategories (Pure Juction Table)
```

Entity Type:

```
CmsContent
CmsCategory
```

Entyt Set:

```
CmsContents
CmsCategories
```

I have some Navigational Properties:

```
for CmsContents --> CmsCategories --> Return Collection of Cms CmsCategory
for CmsCategories --> CmsContents --> Return Collection of Cms CmsContents
```

Data in DataBase for the Junction Table is presented:

```
CategoryId     ContentId
7              1
7              2
9              2
```

I need query Entity Framwork to retrive all CmsContents which are included in the Junction Table.

At the moment I use this code:

```
var contents = from cnt in context.CmsContents
                               where cnt.CmsCategories.Any()
                               select cnt;
```

That Returns:

```
CmsContents
1
2
```

I need the result showing instead:

```
CmsContents
1
2
2
```

I suspect that Any() show me just DISTINCT values, but I need all values listed.

Any idea how to solve it?.

Could you please write me the LINQ query so I can have a clear picture.

Comment: It's not just showing you distinct values -- you're only querying distinct values. It looks like you need to do a join.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Any()` doesn't return values at all - it returns a *Boolean* value as to whether there are any values in the collection or not. It's just showing two values because you're only querying CmsContents, which has two rows, and both rows have at least one category, so both rows are in the result.

It looks like you're really after something like:

```
var contents = from cnt in context.CmsContents
               from category in cnt.CmsCategories
               select cnt;
```

Comment: Jon,many thanks for your answer. It is working great! Thanks once again for your help :-)